# Make a double headed mechanism arrow in mol2chemfig

Tags: tikz-arrows, chemfig, mol2chemfig

I want to use a double headed mechanism arrow to indicate that a carbonyl bond is breaking and reforming with the expel of the leaving group.

My code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\colorlet{mcfpusharrowcolor}{red}%<----- Added to change the color of the curved arrows

%\tikzset{ 
 %   }

\setchemfig{bond offset=1pt,atom sep=2em,compound sep=5em,arrow offset=10pt,arrow coeff=1.25}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section*{Claisen Condensation}
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
          % 1
    -[:30]% 2
             (
       -[:330]OEt% 3
             )
    =[:90]O% 4
}
\arrow{<=>[\ch{NaOEt}][]}
\chemfig{
           % 1
     =[@{DB}:30]% 2
              (
         -[@{OCB}:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}@{OM}% 4
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 3
}
\arrow{<=>[\chemfig{
           % 1
    -[:30]@{CC}% 2
             (
       -[@{COET}:330]@{OET}OEt% 3
             )
    =[@{ODB}:90]@{O}O% 4
}][]}[,2]
\chemfig{
           OEt% 2
    -[:150]% 1
              (
         =[:90]O% 3
              )
    -[:210]% 4
              (
        -[:240]H% 8
              )
              (
        -[:295]H% 9
              )
    -[:150]% 5
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:210]% 7
}
\arrow{<->>[\chemfig{^{\ominus}OEt}][]}[-90]
\chemleft[\subscheme{
\chemfig{
           % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:330]% 3
     =[:30]% 4
              (
         -[:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}% 7
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 5
}\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{
          % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         -[:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}% 6
              )
    =[:330]% 3
     -[:30]% 4
              (
         =[:90]O% 5
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 7
}}\chemright]
\arrow{->[\chemfig{H_3O^{\oplus}}][]}[180]
\chemfig{
           % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:330]% 3
     -[:30]% 4
              (
         =[:90]O% 5
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 7
}
\schemestop
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mcfpusharrow/.style = {
        mcfpusharrowcolor,
        shorten <=1pt,
        shorten >=2pt}
        ]
\mcfpush{DB}{100:25mm}{CC}{150:8mm}
\mcfpush{OM}{-45:8mm}{OCB}{-45:5mm}
\mcfpush{ODB}{-45:4mm}{O}{-45:8mm}
\mcfpush{COET}{90:5mm}{OET}{90:5mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to put the arrow into a different `tikzpicture` environment so you can change the `mcfpusharrow/.style` for this one arrow only without affecting the other arrows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\colorlet{mcfpusharrowcolor}{red}%<----- Added to change the color of the curved arrows

\setchemfig{bond offset=1pt,atom sep=2em,compound sep=5em,arrow offset=10pt,arrow coeff=1.25}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section*{Claisen Condensation}
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
          % 1
    -[:30]% 2
             (
       -[:330]OEt% 3
             )
    =[:90]O% 4
}
\arrow{<=>[\ch{NaOEt}][]}
\chemfig{
           % 1
     =[@{DB}:30]% 2
              (
         -[@{OCB}:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}@{OM}% 4
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 3
}
\arrow{<=>[\chemfig{
           % 1
    -[:30]@{CC}% 2
             (
       -[@{COET}:330]@{OET}OEt% 3
             )
    =[@{ODB}:90]@{O}O% 4
}][]}[,2]
\chemfig{
           OEt% 2
    -[:150]% 1
              (
         =[:90]O% 3
              )
    -[:210]% 4
              (
        -[:240]H% 8
              )
              (
        -[:295]H% 9
              )
    -[:150]% 5
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:210]% 7
}
\arrow{<->>[\chemfig{^{\ominus}OEt}][]}[-90]
\chemleft[\subscheme{
\chemfig{
           % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:330]% 3
     =[:30]% 4
              (
         -[:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}% 7
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 5
}\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{
          % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         -[:90]\mcfright{O}{^{\ominus}}% 6
              )
    =[:330]% 3
     -[:30]% 4
              (
         =[:90]O% 5
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 7
}}\chemright]
\arrow{->[\chemfig{H_3O^{\oplus}}][]}[180]
\chemfig{
           % 1
     -[:30]% 2
              (
         =[:90]O% 6
              )
    -[:330]% 3
     -[:30]% 4
              (
         =[:90]O% 5
              )
    -[:330]OEt% 7
}
\schemestop
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mcfpusharrow/.style = {
        mcfpusharrowcolor,
        shorten <=1pt,
        shorten >=2pt}
        ]
\mcfpush{DB}{100:25mm}{CC}{150:8mm}
\mcfpush{OM}{-45:8mm}{OCB}{-45:5mm}
\mcfpush{COET}{90:5mm}{OET}{90:5mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mcfpusharrow/.style = {
        mcfpusharrowcolor,
        shorten <=1pt,
        shorten >=2pt,
        <->,                               % <--- Double ended arrow
        >=stealth}                         % <--- Same style as other arrows in he diagram
        ]
\mcfpush{ODB}{-45:4mm}{O}{-45:8mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To adjust the arrow head size, you could either use the `scale` option as shown below, or alternatively `length`, `width`, `inset`, `angle`, `scale length`  or `scale width` that are described in sections 16.3.1 and 16.3.2 (page 190-193)  of the [PGF manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mcfpusharrow/.style = {
        mcfpusharrowcolor,
        shorten <=1pt,
        shorten >=2pt,
        {Stealth[scale=1.5]}-{Stealth[scale=1.5]},}  % <--- Double ended arrow, same style as others, scaled arrow tips
        ]
\mcfpush{ODB}{-45:4mm}{O}{-45:8mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have one more question. How can I adjust the size of the arrowhead? It is difficult to recognize it on a printout.

Comment: @heisenberg_px: I have edited my answer to contain some information on how to change the size and dimensions of the arrow heads. Hopefully this helps.